# Where exactly do I ask for software identification?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I recently asked a [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48125/23377) about not  able to recognize a TTS engine on "Software Recommendations" and it was quickly put off topic. I'm confused to where do I post such a question regarding the recognition of a specific software.

**The original post I made on the Software Recommendations Q&A:-**

**The link to the question:-**

> [Can't recognize old TTS engine/file](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48125/36431)

**The Question:-**

> I have heard it many times before, but I can't recognize where the TTS file/engine comes from.
>
> This is an example of the TTS:-
>   [Old TTS](http://clyp.it/fjxhz2bw)
>
> I finally found it on [this online TTS tool](http://www.text2speech.org), the "US Male" but I still have no clue where it comes from. I was hoping that y'all could recognize it and recommend me the TTS file. Thanks in advance.
>
> **Edit:**
>   I need recommendations on a TTS software that has the exact following voice:-
>
> [Old TTS](http://clyp.it/fjxhz2bw)

Comment: It could greatly help if you put the entire text of the question in a blockquote. I'd do it but I'm lazy and on mobile.

Comment: Any specific reasons why ? This is my first post in the meta.

Comment: Should I add the original question in this post ?

Comment: You could try [retrocomputing.SE]. For some questions there may be no appropriate stack, even if they are good ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like even [Super User](https://superuser.com) does not like software identification questions: see [this Meta discussion](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6073/442468).

The general problem with identification questions is that they're generally only useful for a single user, and do not benefit the community in the long run. That, combined with the tendency of these kind of posts to be of low quality, has led to many Stack Exchange communities not allowing any identification questions at all, or only if they meet strict quality guidelines.

Comment: "...these questions aren't educational in any way, because there's no way to learn about the process of discovery. A particular community member, by virtue of their experience in the field, just happens to be able to take the limited information you remembered and fill in enough of the blanks to guess the correct answer... guessing game questions do not meet our goal of making the Internet better." (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game)

Comment: It isn't *particularly* a SUish question to me either. Also, the about page on the site he linked says "This tool uses CMU Flite as TTS." soooooo I'd downvote for lack of research, even if it was.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek me neither, but it's not explicitly excluded by the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Well, its such a vague question I don't even know what platform its own